# Rewrite rule to change the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite a URL like:

```
http://domainname.com/all-studio-methods
```

To:

```
http://domainname.com/review.php?id=25&cas=all-studio-methods
```

My `.htaccess` file currently looks like the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]*)$ review.php?id=$1&cas=$2 [L]
```

But it is not working properly.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you intend to get "25" from?

Comment: You cannot obtain `id` parameter out of nowhere (since you do have it in original URL). Your only option right now (to have such rewrite working **without changing the php code**) is to create a specific rule for such URL (it will work on this URL **only**): e.g. `RewriteRule ^all-studio-methods$ review.php?id=25&cas=all-studio-methods [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]*)$ review.php?id=$1&cas=$2 [L]
```

The `$1` and `$2` are backreferences that are replaced with matched groupings in your reqular expression, `^([^/\.]*)$` which only has 1 grouping, the entire match. So `$2` will always be blank since you don't have another grouping. This also means that `$1` will be the entire match (e.g. **all-studio-methods**) and you're going to get a URI like this:

```
review.php?id=all-studio-methods&cas=
```

Which is obvioiusly not what you want. The comments ask where the `id=25` comes from. It's not coming from the URI, `/all-studio-methods`. So in order to rewrite to `id=25`, it's got to be in the URI somewhere, for example:

```
http://domainname.com/25-all-studio-methods
```

Then you'd have a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^/\.]*)$ review.php?id=$1&cas=$2 [L]
```

If you really don't want the `25-` in the URI, you'll need to rewrite the php code in `review.php` so that it doesn't take an id. It would need to fetch the ID internally from the database given a `cas`.

Or, you could create [a rewrite map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) in order to map `cas` to an id. It's going to be pretty much the same thing, you're writting code to do it in either case.